# EventSource message not shown

Tags: javascript, php

I tried a sample of js eventsource and PHP. It works fine in local but when i sent it to a remote server, the message only shows after the php process completes. Can help me with this issue please? 
Here is the code.
PHP.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
// recommended to prevent caching of event data.
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

function send_message($id, $message, $progress) {
    $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress);

    echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: " . json_encode($d) . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;

    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

//LONG RUNNING TASK
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    send_message($i, 'on iteration ' . $i . ' of 10' , $i*10); 
    sleep(1);
}

send_message('CLOSE', 'Process complete');
```

HTML/JS.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="eventlist"></ul>
</body>
<script>
  var eventList = document.getElementById('eventlist');
  var evtSource = new EventSource("ssedemo.php");
  evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    var newElement = document.createElement("li");
    newElement.innerHTML = "message: " + e.data;
    //console.log(eventList);
    //console.log("hello");      
    eventList.appendChild(newElement);
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want we guess your code?

Comment: yep. I just added the code in my question.